# Having trouble getting Rails form builder to respect a given time zone for a time_select input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, timezone

I **cannot** get my rails input helpers to respect a given time zone. I've looked at all the existing issues on this subject and code examples. It seems like this should be simple, but I'm getting nowhere. I'm hoping someone here can quickly see the error of my ways:

I have a `Pro` model in Rails with a `time` field called "work_start_time".

```
# schema.rb
create_table "pros", force: true do |t|
    t.time     "work_start_time"
```

I have a very basic form for my Pro that includes some additional lines to help me debug:

```
Work_start_time in UTC:<br>
<%= @pro.work_start_time %><br>

Work_start_time in PST:<br>
<% Time.use_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)") do %>
  <%= @pro.work_start_time.in_time_zone %><br>
<% end %>

Form for work_start_time using PST:<br>
<%= form_for @pro do |f| %>
  <% Time.use_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)") do %>
    <%= f.time_select :work_start_time %><br>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Now I would expect the second and third times to be the same, since they're both supposed to be displayed in PST. But the time_select fails to respect it and shows the time in UTC instead:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?? I've tried using datetime_select. I've tried providing the work_start_time as a `value:` argument to the select method. No dice.

This is a simplified example - normally the time zone is actually a stored current_user.time_zone and we set Time.use_zone as an around_filter in the application controller. But those are disabled for this simplified experiment.

Ruby 2.2 (same issue with 2.0)
Rails 4.1.8 (same issue with 4.2.6 and Ruby 2.2)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried using Time.use_zone do, but you might try adding to_s to the end of your @pro.work_start_time.in_time_zone call.  Alternatively you could also use Moment.js and Moment time zone and render in javascript.

I found it easier to have the front end use moment to return utc times in forms, and to convert utc times to a default time zone.

Comment: `@pro.work_start_time.in_time_zone` is actually displaying the time correctly in PST, it's the call to `f.time_select :work_start_time` that isn't. I'd prefer not to tack on an entire javascript library to fix on bit of functionality that's supposedly handled by Rails already. But as a last resort, it could work.